# Having trouble using For/Next with variables

Tags: excel, vba, label, userform

I am using an excel Userform and on the form I have created several label fields that are named in sequential order.  For example:
Label1, Label2...LabelX
I want to assign the .caption for them from an array that I have built separately.  Using a For/Next loop makes the most sense in my head, but since it is a label, I am having trouble.  I cannot even get the code to take in a way that makes sense.  Below is what I was trying...

```
For i = 1 To 100
    Labeli.Caption = Array(i)
Next i
```

If there is a way to keep it inside of the loop, it would make the code a lot less cumbersome.  Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: So you want to 'refer to a control of a userform by a variable', what should be your question to a seatch engiine- In addition vba arrays are zero based by default, first element is array(0).

Comment: @ComputerVersteher  I am wanting to display all related items in a list, my list of labels, for a user to quickly see what they need.  It's a recipe of sorts.  Is a label considered a control?  I noticed in a comment below you mentioned a collection.  That one is new to me, so I will research that a bit more.  My initial research tells me that might be a better approach than the way I have chosen to go.  Also, I did not realize that arrays were zero based, but I manually load the array starting at one.  I suppose (0) will always be empty in this example.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: That sounds like a database task and continuous subform usage, so Ms Access would be my suggestion (at least as frontend). You allready use a database or is data stored in excel?  But that is OT here. Have a look at Access Forms and Subforms to see if they fit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
i = 1

For Each itm In Me.Controls

    If itm.Name = "Label" & i Then
        itm.Caption = Array(i)
        i = i + 1
    End If

Next
```

You cannot form an Object Name like `Labeli` where i is a Variable. But you can loop through all the controls and check if that Label have a Name like `Label1` and so on.

---

**Another Method:**

```
For i = 1 To 100
        Me.Controls("Label" & i).Caption = Array(i)
Next
```

Comment: If you know the name why loop theiugh controls as you can refer by name in collection?

Comment: I like it, avoids the problem of non-existing names! Could be improved with a test if 
 `itm` is actually an object of type `Label`.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher .. Both Methods work. I am used to do this, so I posted this one :)

Comment: @L8n OP has an array prefilled, so we can suggest almost all labels exist and if not he want to recognize (by a raised and catched error), Assuming 100 labels that ends up in at least (if no ather controls) 100 * 50 iterations (100 controls, average loop through collection is about 50), compared to 100 if collection is used without loop (2. method).

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback on this.  I used your second method and it worked very well for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you can to is "build" the name of the Labels like this:

`Userform.Controls("Label" & i).Caption`

`Userform` is a Reference to the Userform, if you write it the codebehind of the Userform you can use `Me.`

But if you have a hundred Labels, there may be better ways to create your Userform, this looks a bit like a [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: There are really only 12 for this, sorry.  There are hundreds of things in a list and I search for related ones and store them in an array that can hold up to 12.  I just got confused when typing.  You are probably right about the XY Problem though.  The discussion using "Me" helps clear a lot of things up for me too.  Thanks for your help and feedback.